# Scrollbars if form larger than screen

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm needing some assistance with what I can tell a vendor developing a form in an application I don't have the source to. We've found a bug with one of their large Winforms where if it's opened in an RDP session at 1024x768, the bottom 250px or so of the form which is ~1000px high is unreachable.

They're being difficult about saying there's no solution which I know to be nonsense, but I don't have a Visual Studio environment presently set up to build a proof of concept to test for myself and then show them otherwise.

From what I can tell from other StackOverflow questions and MSDN documentation pages, something like the following should resolve the problem so the form will auto-size to the maximum displayable height then put a vertical scrollbar in to allow viewing the bottom part of the form. Will the following achieve my goal?

```
public MyTallForm()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  this.AutoScroll = true
  this.AutoSize = true
}
```

Comment: To whoever has downvoted this question, please elaborate on why so I can resolve the issue. Or, as is more likely, don't.

Comment: I did not downvote but i can understand why someone would; with practically no information given about the implementation of the form and its controls it is impossible to say for sure if this will work, or what combination or change would have to be made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AutoSize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.autosize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) responds to change in controls inside the form by growing & shrinking the form as needed.

[AutoScroll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a62htd5x(v=vs.110).aspx) responds to change in controls inside the form by displaying/hiding the scrollbars.

Thus, AutoScroll won't be activated if AutoSize is active since the form is always large enough. If the problem is from too small display resolution, you'll want AutoScroll.

If the form kept open between RDP sessions, you might need to subscribe to [DisplaySettingsChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.displaysettingschanged(v=vs.110).aspx) to be aware of resolution changes, and either simply [Maximize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.windowstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) (not sure if it's already maximized, toggling to Minimized and back to Maximized perhaps?) or use [GetWorkingArea](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1a92hss5(v=vs.110).aspx) if you need detailed size.

Comment: To clarify, are you saying that I'll only need to tell them to set `this.AutoScroll = true` on initialization for it to not allow the form's height to be greater than the available resolution of the screen or RDP session? The form won't be left open between sessions so that simplifies it a bit at least.

Comment: @bdx `WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized` and `AutoScroll = true` on initialization "should" work if the controls act similar to microsoft controls

Answer (score 3):

Set `AutoScroll = True` and `AutoScaleMode to Dpi` In Form Properties[image: See attached image]

Hope it helps.